# How can I fix the autosize() issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to make a simple orgchart builder and using autosize() to change the number of rows in the textarea dynamically. It works great up until the user creates a new node and tries to re-edit the parent node.

I also have some simple code for resizing the cols for text areas with less than a row of content. I started coding something like it for the rows but can't seem to figure it out. I was hoping to make something lightweight to use instead of the plug-in.

Note that all my personal jquery code is labeld at the very end of the "javascript".
[Heres the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B9L9n/1/)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Also another bonus question: Whats the best way I could draw the lines between the nodes? Like in a drop down tree style?